# Can't we install scala IDE for windows 7 32 bit machine?

Tags: scala

I am trying to install scala IDE in my windows 7 32 bit machine .

When i launch it it  throws  compatible error.

Attaching the screenshot as well

[image]

Where do i get scala eclipse ide for windows 7 32 bit machine ?

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: You could download a 32-bit Eclipse and try installing the Scala IDE packages from the update site? See http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html

Comment: Ok Sure. I will do that

Answer (score 0):

We don't have SCALA IDE available for Windows 32 bit. In this case what we can do is install 32 bit Eclipse and install Scala as plugin. We can find the plugin links at http://scala-ide.org/download/prev-stable.html