# Unable to install Scala IDE for Windows 7 32 bit machine

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-marketplace

I have tried to find Scala IDE for Windows 7 32-bit machine from various sources but unable to find and install it.

When I launch it, the following error is shown:

[image: eclipse version not compatible]

I also tried to add plugins and packages but I am not able to access marketplace.

I referred to the following links but nothing works for me:

- [Can't we install scala IDE for windows 7 32 bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290851/cant-we-install-scala-ide-for-windows-7-32-bit-machine)
- [Can't access Eclipse marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794885/cant-access-eclipse-marketplace)
- [Can't access Eclipse marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794885/cant-access-eclipse-marketplace/25337453#25337453)

How can I install Scala IDE?

Answer (score 0):

The Scala IDE bundle is only offered for 64 bit, but the plug-in [seems not require a 64 bit Java JRE](http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html#requirements):

1. Install Java 32 bit
2. Install an [Eclipse 32 bit package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) (see [*What Eclipse package should I use?*](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/faq/index.html#what-eclipse-package-should-i-use))
3. In *Help > Install New Software...* work with `http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e46/scala212/stable/site`